# Is there a zero-overhead consuming iterator?

Tags: rust

I often find myself writing code like:

```
myvec.iter().map(|x| some_operation(x)).count()
```

The invocation of `count` triggers the iterator chain to be consumed, but also produces as non-unit result which is undesired.

I am looking for something like

```
myvec.iter().map(|x| some_operation(x)).consume()
```

which should be equivalent to

```
for _ in myvec.iter().map(|x| some_operation(x)) {}
```

Comment: I'm curious what you want to do in the iterates. Both your examples use `map`, which is designed to transform an item. Throwing away that result means that the entire iterator was useless.

Comment: For some reason I felt like not using a for loop anymore. Don't ask me why, maybe this question is relatively useless.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, Rust does not have this.

There [were](http://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/2s5jjs/does_having_foreach_implemented_for_iterators/) [several](http://discuss.rust-lang.org/t/add-foreach-method-to-iterators-for-side-effects/1312) discussions and even [an RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/582) about having a `for_each()` operation on iterators which will execute a closure for each element of an iterator, consuming it, but nothing is there yet.

Consider using `for` loop instead:

```
for x in myvec.iter() {
    some_operation(x);
}
```

In this particular case it does look better than iterator operations.

Comment: I agree, it does look better, and maybe this is why there is no consuming iterator yet. It might make those blinded by iterators rethink their particular use-case.

Answer (score 9):

[`Iterator::for_each`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.for_each) does what you want:

```
struct Int(i32);

impl Int {
    fn print(&self) {
        println!("{}", self.0)
    }
}

fn main() {
    [Int(1), Int(2), Int(3)].into_iter().for_each(Int::print);
}
```